Meaning of "Harsh handfuls" in "Fat City" by Leonard Gardner
From chapter 4 of the novel Fat City (1969) by Leonard Gardner:

With a bowl and a carton of salt he retired to the bathroom. There he mixed a solution that he snuffed up his nostrils over the basin, a remedy Ruben Luna had recommended for toughening the interior of the nose. Sucked into his head, the warm salt water trickled down his throat. He choked, spat into the basin and, sneezing, sprayed his face in the mirror with blood-tinted drops. He snuffed in harsh handfuls, pinched his nostrils shut and dabbed the solution on his swollen brows, the make-up dissolving over his fingers like the pigment of his skin. He shook salt from the box and caked it on his eyelids and lips. When he released the brine from his outraged nose, cords of mucus dangled out after it. Sneezing and coughing, his eyes watering, he went on dabbing and snuffing.

Does "harsh handfuls" mean, "he sniffed handful after handful of the salt water"? Or, "his cupped hands were full of the salt water and he snuffed it all in"?

The plural 'handfuls' suggests that he did it repeatedly.

@KateBunting thank you. Couldn't it mean " handfuls of the harsh solution" and somehow the author used the synecdoche. And could the plural "handfuls" mean " with two cupped hands"?

Yes, I was assuming that harsh referred to the saltiness of the water.  I don't think it can mean 'one lot of water held in both hands'.

@KateBunting thank you so much.

He sniffed up or snuffed (up)  handfuls of the solution into his nose, but not sniffled.

@Lambie thank you.
