Meaning of "caked it on his eyelids and lips" in "Fat City" by Leonard Gardner
From chapter 4 of the novel Fat City (1969) by Leonard Gardner:

With a bowl and a carton of salt he retired to the bathroom. There he mixed a solution that he snuffed up his nostrils over the basin, a remedy Ruben Luna had recommended for toughening the interior of the nose. Sucked into his head, the warm salt water trickled down his throat. He choked, spat into the basin and, sneezing, sprayed his face in the mirror with blood-tinted drops. He snuffed in harsh handfuls, pinched his nostrils shut and dabbed the solution on his swollen brows, the make-up dissolving over his fingers like the pigment of his skin. He shook salt from the box and caked it on his eyelids and lips. When he released the brine from his outraged nose, cords of mucus dangled out after it. Sneezing and coughing, his eyes watering, he went on dabbing and snuffing.

Does the sentence in bold mean "he poured some salt into a bowl, then he mixed it with water, and finally placed a crust of it on his eyelids and lips."?
And did the author omit those details to avoid repetition?

since his hands are wet and full of water, there's no need for a bowl in this process, and one isn't mentioned  (The fuller quote is in https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/28146/meaning-of-harsh-handfuls-in-fat-city-by-leonard-gardner )

@KateGregory thank you so much. yes you're right. I didn't notice that. So he poured it in his hand.

It means he got some on a fingertip and daubed (applied) it to his lips and eyelids and lips.  That said, it's hard to imagine doing that without some little bit of water.

@Lambie thank you so much.

@KateGregory please turn your comment into an answer. When correct answers are provided in comments, it's a disincentive for anyone else to furnish an answer, but that leaves us with unanswered questions in our stats. Thanks!

@verbose it's not really an answer, I'm just pointing out the bowl is superfluous
